# создание БД в MySQL Спорт

Tags: mysql

можете помочь воссоздать данную БД. на создании внешнего ключа произошла ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
create table Athlete (Full_Name varchar(11),
Year_of_birth int(4),
Command varchar(11),
Sports_category varchar(11),
ID_Athlete integer)

create table Kind_of_sport (ID_Kind integer,
Name_Kind varchar(11),
Unit varchar(11),
Record int(11),
Date char(10))

create table Competition (ID_Competition integer,
Name varchar(11),
Date char(10),
Kind_ID integer,
FOREIGN KEY(Kind_ID)
REFERENCES Kind_of_sport(ID_Kind)) ///на этом моменте возникла ошибка
```

Comment: Создаваемый FK обязан ссылаться на UNIQUE индекс. Которым тут даже не пахнет.

Comment: Не вижу у вас в DDL создания первичных ключей. Хотя на рисунке они есть.

Comment: innodb (кому должен всем прощает), т.е. позволяет создавать fk, ссылающийся на не уникальный индекс (но делать так не надо). А что это за тип такой null(8)?

Answer (score 0):

создайте primary индексы, отмеченные на диаграмме ключами

укажите в явном виде тип таблиц - innodb

если ошибка останется, приводите полный текст ошибки и результат выполнения команды SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS (секцию LATEST)

полный список причин возникновения ошибок внешних ключей есть в этой [статье](https://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/30.html)